# How can i expose class method in V8

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

**How can i expose class method in V8 context?**

I woud like to create something like following line, but it wont work do to fact that lambda with captures can not be treated as fuction pointer.

```
Global()->Set("foo",v8::FunctionTemplate::New([this](const v8::Arguments &args) -> v8::Handle<v8::Value>{this->foo()}; return v8::Undefined()));
```

It is not about exposing literal type as `struct Point {int x,y}` but about exposing class method, or simple callable object.

Comment: can you add a link to the documentation of `Set`. applicable solutions depend a bit on what functionality you have.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I did to achieve it.

```
context->Global()->Set(v8::String::New("_this"),v8::External::Wrap(this));
context->Global()->Set(v8::String::New("foo"),v8::FunctionTemplate::New(
    [](const v8::Arguments  &args) -> v8::Handle<v8::Value>{
         reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(reinterpret_cast<v8::External*>(*(args.This()->Get(v8::String::New("engine"))))->Value())->foo();
         return v8::Undefined();
})->GetFunction());
```